# Upload file to Amazon S3 and assign callback for percentage uploaded

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there an easy way to assign callback function for percentage uploaded in PHP - Amazon s3.
Something similar to this
[File Download](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=amazons3/register_streaming_write_callback)

but for upload?

Answer (score 2):

The AWS SDK for php 1.2.6 includes a runnable sample in **_samples/cli-s3_progress_bar.php**.
which shows tracking upload/download progress.

**Download here**
http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/PHP/1553377899765189

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case I do not want include the whole SDK into project - is there any API for this? I see registered_streaming_write_callback at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#p=CFRequest but do not see examples of how to pass that.